# DateTime value binds hour incorrectly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime, data-binding, datetime-format, editorfor

I have an `@HTML.EditorFor` on an order form page where the user selects a time to pick up an order. I save the value in a Session and gets picked up by the Review page. The user can decide to edit where they are sent back to the order form with their previous values bound. All other values bind correctly except the pickup time, but only the hour. The minutes bind correctly, but for some reason the hour always displays as 3. I've watched the value while debugging; the value is always correct even after binding, but it always displays as 3.

## My Model

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Pickup time is required")]
[DisplayName("Pickup time")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:h:mm tt}")]
[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
public DateTime PickupTime { get; set; }
```

## My View

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Order.PickupTime, new { htmlAttributes = new 
{ @class = "form-control" } })
```

I'm creating a new Order object from the view model:

```
Order order = new Order() {
    PickupTime = ofvm.Order.PickupTime
};
```

I've tried different DataFormatStrings, using TempData and ViewBags instead of Sessions. The value is always correct in all those, but still no matter what the hour value is, it always displays as 3. Does anyone have any idea what is happening?

Comment: Which is the controller which get the wrong bind ? and the DatePicker code? in theory if you use EditorFor, the server have to get the DateTime correctly.

Comment: @JordiJordi - I'm using eonasdan's bootstrap-datetimepicker for the time picker and creating a DateTime object in the controller. Edited my question to show how I'm grabbing value.

Comment: OK show me the controller which get the info later, and you say , bind it bad. The action must recive the same Model than the View got now to bind it good

Comment: @JordiJordi - I am using different view models for the order form and review pages, but they both contain the same Order model. Like I said, all other data is being bound correctly (FirstName, LastName, Email, etc) it is literally just the hour of the PickupTime DateTime value that always displays as 3 despite the actual value actually being different.

Comment: Then try to capture, with console log(), the value before sending from the form. You can make it with .submit() of jquery. Surely is problem of language DateTimePicker Eonasdan, sometimes i have this problem

Comment: If not, set DateTimePicker format, example: format:'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Still makes no sense to me as to why it wasn't binding correctly. But what fixed it was adding `.TimeOfDay` to the Linq expression in the `EditorFor` control, so instead of this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Order.PickupTime, new { htmlAttributes = new 
{ @class = "form-control" } }) // Always displayed '3' as the hour, no matter the value
```

I did this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Order.PickupTime.TimeOfDay, new { 
htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } }) // Displays correct hour value
```

and the hour binds correctly now. I thought the `DataFormatString` attribute would be enough since the value is there, but for some reason it just didn't work. So from now on, whenever I need to bind a time value into an `EditorFor` control, I won't be using a format string.